# Questions regarding constructors

Tags: c++, function, class, visual-c++, inheritance

I am working on an assignment and it asks to do the following to my inheritance class:

- A no argument constructor that sets the data section to "0"
- An overloaded constructor that takes a string and sets the data section to the value being passed to it.

**I do not fully understand and would really appreciate it if I could have examples of both.**

I am working on inheritance.

My Number.h class through inheritance.

```
#ifndef Number
#define Number

#include "Double.h"
#include "Integer.h"


class Number : public string

{


};

#endif
```

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @MarcB Everybody could use a little help sometime

Comment: We will give you help if you show some effort and appear you have read the required material from your book. We are not here to do homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Number : public string
{
public:
    Number() : string("0") { }
    Number(const string &str) : string(str) { }
};
```

However, as long as you have the following 2 lines in the beginning, the name `Number` will be replaced by preprocessor.

```
#ifndef Number
#define Number
```

You should use another macro name for the #include guard.

Answer (score 0):

You created the class `Number`. Now you can a new class (I called `SpecialNumber`) that has 2 constructors. The first one does not have parameter and sets the value to `0` while the other constructor gets the paramater to be used as a value for the class.

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

class Number
{
private:
    int myValue;
};

class SpecialNumber : public Number
{
public:
    SpecialNumber()
        : myValue( 0 ) // fixed value
    {
    }

    SpecialNumber( int someValue )
        : myValue( someValue ) // value coming from a parameter
    {
    }
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
Number::Number()
{
    data = "0";
}
Number::Number(string a)
{
    data = a;
}
```